# Error locating DispatcherServlet , no lib directory created using STS IDE

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I am using `STS` for the first time, and using `STS` created a maven based web-application; using Spring MVC framework.

It makes directory structure like below:

[image]

I have configured Apache tomcat withing STS. When I start tomcat withing STS (and this web application getting deployed to tomcat); while trying to access a resource, it is giving the error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

It is evident that it can't locate the DispatcherServlet class.

In the directory structure which `STS` created, it doesn't have any **lib** directory; do I need to manually create the **lib** directory and place run time needed jars into that?

If this is the case, why doesn't maven plugin (which comes pre-configured into STS) make the correct directory structure?

Is there something I am doing wrong or I don't understand the things?

Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by doing this: 1) Close the project 2) Clean the project 3) Enable "Build Automatically" (Project -> "Build Automatically"). I am not sure how this fixed the issue, but it did. I checked the console output of the tomcat, and saw some SEVERE logs, which made me think that if there is any issue in the build/ deployment itself. The issue isn't because of missing "lib" in the directory structure in the STS project view (as I felt initially). Add on: I tried to export the project as .war and all the necessary directory structure got created in the target .war file.